# looping through list of pandas dataframes and make it empty dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a multiple pandas dataframe. I want empty each dataframes like below

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame() 
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
```

Instead of doing it individually, is there any way to do it in one line of code.

Comment: `[df.drop(df.index,inplace=True) for df in [df1,df2]]`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, this will work:

```
df_list = []
for i in range (0,10):
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    df_list.append(df)
print(df_list[0].head())
```